# Bizarre issue with unordered lists having whitespace b/w list-items depending on how the code is written?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am facing a very bizarre issue that I have spent the last night debugging. Finally fixed it but the solution itself bothers me.

I am trying to build the following header:

[image: original]

Here's the code that I am using:

```
<div class="header-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="header-nav-active" href="/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="/opportunities.html">Opportunities</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/team.html">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="/team.html">Writing</a></li>
    <li><a href="/team.html">Fellowship</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This code actually renders the following:

[image: bad render]

After spending hours debugging what's going on, apparently having list items on new lines was the issue. If I have all list items on the same line, it works:

```
<li><a class="header-nav-active" href="/">About</a></li><li><a href="/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li><li><a href="/opportunities.html">Opportunities</a></li><li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li><li><a href="/team.html">Team</a></li><li><a href="/team.html">Writing</a></li><li><a href="/team.html">Fellowship</a></li>
```

[image: good render bad code]

Can someone explain what is going on here? Am I missing some core concepts about unordered lists or HTML? I can't have list items on new lines?

### Appendix

#### CSS

If CSS code is required:

```
.header-nav {
  padding-top: 2.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 4.6rem;
}

.header-nav>ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 6px 0 7.5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dce6f0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dce6f0;
}

.header-nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.51rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
  border-right: 1px solid #dce6f0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header-nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(4n) {
  padding-right: 0;
  border-right: none;
}

.header-nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.header-nav>ul>li>a {
  color: #828c96;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

#### Firefox Inspector note

Please note that with newlines, I could see "whitespace" elements being added by firefox inspector.

[image: whitespace elements in inspector]